# MySQL 1005 error when creating table using InnoDB engine

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-error-1005

When I try to create a table with the following definition,

```
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `x_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `y_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `z_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `status` TINYINT unsigned NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE INDEX(x_id, y_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

an `OperationalError` occurs:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError:
(1005, "Can't create table 'xxx.frm' (errno: -1)")
```

It works if I remove the trailing `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

What is the reason behind this?

The MySQL version is
`mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.84, for pc-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.2`

Comment: That `CREATE` statement works for me.

Comment: Please see if you have InnoDB table space properly created, initialized, and your database server has permission to write into it.

Comment: @Adam it seems that this is a version specific problem?

Comment: @cababunga I guess that's no the reason, because other table definitions setting `ENGINE=InnoDB` works smoothly in my `sql` script.

Comment: Do you really get complaint about 'xxx.frm' when you create table 'demo'? That's really strange. Please also check file system permissions for /var/lib/mysql/`databasename`, or wherever your instance is installed into.

Answer (score 3):

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error message.
>
> If MySQL reports an error number 1005 from a CREATE TABLE statement, and the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. Similarly, if an ALTER TABLE fails and it refers to error 150, that means a foreign key definition would be incorrectly formed for the altered table. You can use **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS** to display a detailed explanation of the most recent InnoDB foreign key error in the server.

[Foreign Key Constraints - Error 1005](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
CREATE TABLE  `demo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `x_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `z_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `x_id` (`x_id`,`y_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please refer this article for more detail, http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mysql/mysql-error-1005-hy000

Comment: But there's no foreign keys in my definition.