# Cannot create interconnecting table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

i'm trying to create a table with columns that reference toward other tables.
How do i make the foreign keys?

Scheme:
[image]

Query: (not working):

```
CREATE TABLE gebruikers_trainingen (
    gebruiker_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    training_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    gebruiker_naam VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    training_naam VARCHAR(255),

    CONSTRAINT fk_idGebruiker FOREIGN KEY (gebruiker_id)
    REFERENCES gebruikers(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_idTraining FOREIGN KEY (training_id)
    REFERENCES trainingen(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_naamGebruiker FOREIGN KEY (gebruiker_naam)
    REFERENCES gebruikers(voornaam),
    CONSTRAINT fk_naamTraining FOREIGN KEY (training_naam)
    REFERENCES trainingen(naam)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Getting:

> Error Code: 1005 Can't create table 'konecranes.gebruikers_trainingen'
>   (errno: 150)

EDIT:
Other tables' queries.

```
CREATE TABLE gebruikers (
    id int unsigned NOT NULL,
    voornaam varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    achternaam varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    account_level int unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, voornaam)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE trainingen (
    id int unsigned NOT NULL,
    naam varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, naam)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add indexes on your foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE gebruikers_trainingen (
    gebruiker_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    training_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    gebruiker_naam VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    training_naam VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    INDEX (gebruiker_id, gebruiker_naam),
    INDEX (training_id, training_naam),

    CONSTRAINT fk_idGebruiker FOREIGN KEY (gebruiker_id, gebruiker_naam) 
    REFERENCES gebruikers(id, voornaam),

    CONSTRAINT fk_idTraining FOREIGN KEY (training_id, training_naam) 
    REFERENCES trainingen(id, naam)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: Sadly, still no success. These foreign keys are a pain :c

Comment: Still the same error ? Could you also post your create code for the 2 other tables ?

Comment: Thanks alot. We did a simultaneous post, as you can see it worked out by adding the constraints together. I did not add the indexes to the other tables when that happened so it might be unnecessary but the indexes in the gebruikers_trainingen table are in fact necessary because before that the way i solved it did not work also therefore i set your answer as solution ;).

Comment: You're right, it's cleaner to group columns, i'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Has this table existed before in a different guise?

[Mysql 1005 error when creating table using InnoDB engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213013/mysql-1005-error-when-creating-table-using-innodb-engine)

Hth Oli

Comment: It hasn't existed before no:(

Answer (score 0):

Merging the constraints as follows did work it out. Also thanks too Justin Lurman for helping me out, had to add Indexes aswell.

```
CONSTRAINT fk_gebruikers FOREIGN KEY (gebruiker_id, gebruiker_naam) REFERENCES gebruikers(id, voornaam),
CONSTRAINT fk_trainingen FOREIGN KEY (training_id, training_naam) REFERENCES trainingen(id, naam)
```